# R no longer accepting timezones in the format GMT+n/GMT-n

Tags: r, timezone, timezone-offset

`?timezones` states `"Most platforms support time zones of the form GMT+n and GMT-n, which assume at a fixed offset from UTC (hence no DST)."`

I have old code from earlier this year where I use `tz="GMT-8"`. Only changes to my computer have been updating to R version `"R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)"` and migrating my library from an old user account by adding a line of code to my Rprofile located in `"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.2\library\base\R"`. Just to be detailed code was `.libPaths(c("C:/Users/XXXX XXXX/Documents/R/win-library/3.2",.Library.site))`. Why might my system suddenly not accept this tz format? What system setting can I change to resolve this?

**Working example below.**

```
tdat<-c("11/19/2014 12:45", "11/19/2014 13:00", "11/19/2014 13:15", 
"11/19/2014 13:30", "11/19/2014 13:45", "11/19/2014 14:00", "11/19/2014 14:15", 
"11/19/2014 14:30", "11/19/2014 14:45", "11/19/2014 15:00")

as.POSIXct(strptime(tdat,"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M",tz="GMT-8"))

Warning messages:
1: In strptime(tdat, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M", tz = "GMT-8") :
  unknown timezone 'GMT-8'
2: In as.POSIXct.POSIXlt(strptime(tdat, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M", tz = "GMT-8")) :
  unknown timezone 'GMT-8'
3: In as.POSIXlt.POSIXct(x, tz) : unknown timezone 'GMT-8'
```

Comment: Suggest removing `R` tag, as per Note in `timezones`: "Note that except where replaced, the operation of time zones is an OS service, and even where replaced a third-party database is used and can be updated (see the section on ‘Time zone names’). Incorrect results will never be an R issue, so please ensure that you have the courtesy not to blame R for them."

Comment: IMHO the R tag is fine here, as not writing the question in an accusatory tone or complaining to r-devel probably suffices to adhere to the spirit of the request to "avoid blaming R".

Comment: Try `tz="Etc/GMT-8"`

Comment: @AlexeyFerapontov , Yes no animosity here. R is a fantastic program!

Comment: @DavidArenburg your solution worked. Can you please share how you came up with this and why it works? Maybe explain in an answer. Much thanks!

Comment: When I have a doubt I use Google. Try Googling "R time zones". I don't know what changed and if. See `?news` if you want to search for updates programatically.

Comment: Be careful.  `Etc/GMT-8` is actually GMT+8.  The signs are inverted.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If your platform is using the standard [tzdb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database) time zones, then you can indeed specify fixed whole-hour zones in the form: `Etc/GMT+8`.

However, be aware:

- The sign is inverted from what you probably expect.  `Etc/GMT-8` is in China.  `Etc/GMT+8` is in America.
- There are plenty of real world time zones that use half-hour or 45-minute offsets, which cannot be represented in this form.
- This does not account for daylight saving time, or other historical changes in time zones.

Therefore, the better idea is to use *named* time zones, as found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

For example, for US Pacific Time, use `America/Los_Angeles`, as it correctly accounts for daylight saving time, alternating between UTC-8 and UTC-7 .

Comment: Oh OK. Thank you I was noticing some strange behavior which was explained by the inverted sign. I'm simply manipulating time series data and need it in PST so this solution works. Read through you links and was able to find information which explains using `Etc/GMT-n`. So this makes more sense now. Again thank you. Cheers.

Comment: Sure.  Just remember, PST is only Pacific Standard Time.  If you need it to match what is actually in use by Pacific Time, then you need to consider Pacific Daylight Time (PDT) as well.  UTC-8 is not used during the summer.